# Can jQuery perform a compound select against the top level only? (a.k.a. "How to avoid chaining children")

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Basically, is there a way to write

```
a.children('.outer').children('.inner')
```

without the intermediate selector?  I can't write

```
$('.outer > .inner', a)
```

because I don't want to do  full-depth search against `a` — I know that the `.outer` elements are immediate children of `a`.

It's partly a matter of "elegance", but partly because I'm trying to avoid "throwaway" element sets.  Yes, jQuery may in effect do the same thing, but it has a better chance of optimizing (at least in theory), when it knows the full query's intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to start with the immediate children, not doing a full-depth search on `.outer` to start:

```
$('> .outer > .inner', a)
```

Or, slightly different, this:

```
a.find('> .outer > .inner')
```

[You can see a demo of both working here](http://jsfiddle.net/6fz25/).

Comment: By God, you're right!  I didn't know you could use that at the front of a query.

Answer (score 2):

The ">" selector is what you need. It will select direct child element, not descendants of all levels: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/